# How to lay gravel on graded underlayment?

Tags: concrete, stairs, masonry, gravel

I am pouring concrete to make a small staircase (5 steps, 8x10" each) over ground underlayment. Since the grade is something like 40 degrees, the gravel rolls down hill and accumulates in the first step. How can I set gravel on a graded underlayment so it doesn't roll down?

Comment: Why do you need gravel on the formwork, on which the concrete is to be placed. Also, do you placed reinforcing steel, if the forwork is elevated above the ground?

Comment: @r13 OK then I don't need it. Yes, I put robust rebar

Comment: Good. Leave the rebars about 2" above the formwork with adequate rebar chairs below (or stone, concrete block) that are able to maintain the rebars in location throughout the pour. Mix the concrete using less water than regularity required so it will be stiffer and more stable on the inclined form. Good luck.

Comment: Forgot to mention, water the form thoroughly the night before the pour, to avoid it absorb too much water from the fresh concrete.

Comment: Wouldn't you have a form for each step that will hold the concrete in place? If so, shouldn't it be holding the gravel in place, too?